# В чем проблема заключается?

Tags: php, webmoney

В настройках webmoney лежит как показано на скриншоте
[image: Настройка webmoney]

```
В файле wm.php лежит
/*$secret = 'ae7aa79503bd5036600a95dd2ed31662';
$data = $_POST;
$key = hash('sha256', $data['LMI_PAYEE_PURSE'].
$data['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'].
$data['LMI_PAYMENT_NO'].
$data['LMI_MODE'].
$data['LMI_SYS_INVS_NO'].
$data['LMI_SYS_TRANS_NO'].
$data['LMI_SYS_TRANS_DATE'].
$secret.
$data['LMI_PAYER_PURSE'].
$data['LMI_PAYER_WM']);


if(strtoupper($key) != $data['LMI_HASH'])
    exit('ошибка');*/
if($_POST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'] < 100){
exit('сумма минимальная');
} else {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Если я уберу комментарий с кусочка кода (то выводит ошибка после обработки платежа), если заверну в комментарий, то работает все. Как это понимать?

Comment: Запустите отладчик и проверьте входные данные на соответствие?

Comment: Как проверить то?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging_ru.html